# How to define the complement of a "region" in $\mathbb{R}^d$ using boxes.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, elementary-set-theory, analytic-geometry

I have a question related to set theory, of which I am a beginner. Please add/change tags if you have better references. Other than describing my main question, I'm also highlighting with the symbol **[?]** the parts I'm really not sure about.

---

**Set up of the problem**

Fix $r\in \mathbb{N}$ and $d\equiv r+\binom{r}{2}$ and consider the region **(plane [?])**
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{B}\equiv \{(b_1,b_2,..., b_d)\in \mathbb{R}^{d}: \text{ } & b_{r+1}=b_1-b_2, b_{r+2}=b_1-b_3, ...,b_{2r-1}=b_1-b_r, \\
&b_{2r}=b_2-b_3, ..., b_{3r-3}=b_2-b_r,\\
&...,\\
& b_d=b_{r-1}-b_r\}
\end{aligned}
$$
For example, when $r=2$ ($d=3$) we have the surface
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{B}\equiv \{(b_1,b_2,b_3)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: \text{ } & b_3=b_1-b_2\}
\end{aligned}
$$
When $r=3$ ($d=6$) we have 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{B}\equiv \{(b_1,..., b_6)\in \mathbb{R}^{6}: \text{ } & b_4=b_1-b_2, b_5=b_1-b_3, b_6=b_2-b_3\}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

**My goal**: I want to write down **the region [?]** that is complement to $\mathcal{B}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ as a union of "boxes".

---

This is how I thought to proceed for $r=2$

Define these two boxes given $(b_1, b_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$
$$
B(b_1, b_2)\equiv \{(x,y,z) \text{ s.t. } x\leq b_1, -y\leq -b_2, z> b_1-b_2\}
$$
$$
Q(b_1, b_2)\equiv \{(x,y,z) \text{ s.t. } x> b_1, -y> -b_2, z\leq  b_1-b_2\}
$$
Then,
$$
\cup_{(b_1, b_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2} B(b_1, b_2)
$$
should be the region **(plane [?])** above $\mathcal{B}$ and 
$$
\cup_{(b_1, b_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2} Q(b_1, b_2)
$$
should be the region **(plane [?])** below $\mathcal{B}$.

Hence, 
$$
\Big\{\cup_{(b_1, b_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2} B(b_1, b_2)\Big\} \cup \Big\{\cup_{(b_1, b_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2} Q(b_1, b_2)\Big \}
$$
is **the region [?]** that is complement to $\mathcal{B}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Is this correct? How do I generalise this to any $r$?

Comment: what is the definition of "open plane above $\mathcal B$"? I am not sure if these are common mathematical objects.

Comment: @supinf Thanks: that's a part I'm confused about. I'm not even sure that $\mathcal{B}$ is a plane given that it is in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Wikipedia defines a plane as a surface for example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry) I really need the help of an expert to clarify every single bit of my question.

Comment: @supinf I've modified my question to make it (I hope) more meaningful to experts. Please help if you can, thanks.

Comment: Isn't it a purely geometrical problem? I ask since you assigned the tag "general topology".

Comment: Thanks: I'm happy to add that tag. I mentioned in the intro that any advise on useful tags is more than appreciated.